# Get data in array by offset id?

Tags: php

i've got a problem with an array. I'm trying to get the `username` by the offset id (0 here).

How can I do that ? I've got an error `Undefined : offset 0`

```
[row] => Array
        (
            [username] => SUNSHINE
        )
```

Thanks you.

```php
echo $check->row['username']; // Supposed to return 'SUNSHINE'
echo $check->row[0]; // Supposed to return 'SUNSHINE'
```

Comment: The offset Is `username` not 0. You are mixing apples And pears... You can use array_values to convert the associative array to a list. Then you can access offset zero, but not username anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use index integer 0 because you are using an associative array.

```
$rowAssoc = ['username' => 'SUNSHINE'];
```

But you can make a numbered array and then access the nth element.

```
$rowNum = array_values($rowAssoc);
var_dump($rowNum[0]);
```

> string(8) "SUNSHINE"